# Some commands are not working inside TCL thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl

```
set t6 [thread::create] ; thread::send -async $t6 "set i1 0"
```

This is working fine without any errors.

```
set t5 [thread::create] ; thread::send -async $t5 "date"
```

But this is erroring out :
invalid command name "date" while executing "date"

What could be the reason ?

Comment: The error message is accurate. Tcl doesn't have a `date` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` “command” is not actually a command. It's another program, `/bin/date` (or `/usr/bin/date`, depending on exactly how your system is set up). Or, on Windows it is a builtin of `CMD.EXE`.

What's going on is that you're using `tclsh` interactively; it detects this and marks the current main interpreter as interactive (sets the global `tcl_interactive` variable to `1`) and the unknown command handler sees that and enables extra behaviours, such as expansion of command names and automatic calling out to external programs; it's effectively rewriting `date` into:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok date]
```

The `auto_execok` command in Tcl does path searching and all the extra stuff required for running inside `bash` or `cmd` (it's got a range of options it can do). On my system, `auto_execok date` returns `/bin/date`, but there's no particular reason why it might do so on yours; all we know is that it found *something*.

The other thread is *not* interactive; it's not talking *directly* to you. That means you need to send it full commands, not abbreviations, not things that are shorthands. It also doesn't write results to the console by default; you need to add that too. Try this:

```
set t5 [thread::create]
thread::send -async $t5 "puts \[[list exec {*}[auto_execok "date"]]\]"
```

This gets messy fast. It's a lot easier to create procedures in the other thread to do most of the work and then call them:

```
set t5 [thread::create]
thread::send $t5 {
    proc runAndPrint {command args} {
        puts [exec {*}[auto_execok $command] {*}$args]
    }
}
thread::send -async $t5 [list runAndPrint "date"]
```

Note that I'm using `list` to build the command to send over when it isn't a literal. I don't need to do that, but it is an extremely good habit to have as it means that your code Just Works As Expected™ when you start passing arguments with spaces and other meta-characters in; you don't have to think about getting quoting right, as `list` does that for you (by design). It's *great* for creating a command to execute and it *guarantees* that there are no surprise substitutions. If you need substitutions, calling a procedure (or lambda term, or method) is so much easier to make reliable; that can `uplevel` and `upvar` if it needs to.

Comment: Printing results is a feature of Tcl's read-eval-print loop. Other threads in a Tcl interpreter don't run such a look; they have a receive-message-eval-send-response loop instead, with the messages being the scripts you send to run.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
I wanted to execute a python script in an async thread.
It is working fine now.